# Show that if a set is finite then there is a unique $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that this set and $n$ are bijection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*My idea*. Assume $X$ is finite and assume Card$(X)=n$. Then, we need to show that there is a bijection $X$ and $n$.

Can you check my idea and can you give a hint?

Comment: Have you proved the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Also $\operatorname{Card}(X)=n$ means *by definition* there is a bijection between $X$ and $n$. What you need to show is that $n$ is the *only* one with a bijection with $X$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Nope. Can you give another method/hint if there is?

Comment: I guess induction based proof, which would essentially be a proof of the pigeonhole principle. (Because this claim is essentially a "stronger" version of the pigeonhole principle.)

Comment: Wait, is this a followup from your previous question?

Comment: Waiting for what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes,it is a followup from my previous question.

Comment: That would have been useful information...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I couldn't use previous question that can you give a hint?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Assume $X$ is finite and assume Card$(X)=n$. Then, we know that there is a bijection between $X$ and $n$ by the definiton of finite. Now, we need to show that $n$ is unique, so, how?

Comment: @Kahler The composition of bijections is a bijection so if it has n and n+k then n and n+k are in bijection. Truncating a bijection gives a bijection and thus the nullset is in bijection with a k element set. But the nullset only bijects with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let X={x_1,...,x_n}, where each element is distinct. Clearly X is not {y_1,...,y_m} where each element is distinct for m not equal to n (for this would induce a bijection on the subscript sets).

Stated otherwise, if X is in bijection with N and N+k then N is in bijection with N+k (by composition). But this is absurd.